# Gradle configurations integration

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've found this code at work in `build.gradle`

```
configurations {
    all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
        }
    }
    integration
}
```

I can't find anywhere what `integration` keyword stands for. Can you explain to me?

Comment: It does not respond to anything in gradle groovy dsl. Can it come from some plugin applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, the build is *declaring* a *new* configuration called `integration`. And a configuration can for the most part be thought of as a bucket or collection of dependencies. If a plugin or the Gradle core new about a particular configuration, there would usually be no need to declare it as it would already exist to begin with.

Let's assume that 'integration' is short for 'integration test'. Then what's going on here is that your build is saying: "Hey, I need a bunch of dependencies for running my integration test, but I don't want to pollute the classpath for the other kinds of runtime environments. So please make me a bucket of dependencies to isolate the integration test".

Later in the build file (which you didn't show), you will then find a `dependencies` block where the `integration` configuration is populated with the modules needed for running the test. And lastly, some task that actually uses it, presumably for setting the classpath.

It could be used for a number of other things of cause. But whatever it is, it is probably something custom and you could rename it (and all references to it) to 'aCollectionOfAwesomeDependenciesUsedForRunningOurIntegrationTest' if you like.